# Css Custom Properties in local scope not working with Gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, postcss, gatsby

**Using:** Gatsbyjs

**Problem:**

Trying to declare css variables at :root (which works very well), but onces I try to override them like that:

```
:root { --feature-background: red; }

:root [data-theme="gradient"] {
  --feature-background: blue;
}

<div data-theme="gradient">Hello</div>
```

I get the following warning and the I get the `fallback` color.

`--feature-background` is not getting overwritten, which is what I expect.

`Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element`

Comment: it's a warning and no error right ?

Comment: That right @TemaniAfif.

Comment: in this case i don't think it's an issue ... a warning is a warning so it won't block you unless you are not getting what you are expecting.

Comment: Well, that is actually my point. My variable is not getting overwritten with my new color. I'll edit my post to be more precise.

Comment: And btw @TemaniAfif  `transform: skewX(-44deg) scaleX(-1) rotate(180deg);
}`

Comment: no ! don't post here, you will spoil everyone :p ... by the way there is a shorter syntax ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif matrix?

Comment: yes there is the matrix as the harder one, but there is another syntax with 2 transform instead of 3